Detecting errors with socket.io emit
I'm making a message exchange system, and I need to make sure that the message sent by a user was sent via websocket.
Below is the socket code and after creating the message within the database.
  socket.emit("send-msg", {
        content,
        friendsId,
        userId,
        receiverId,
      });

const message = prisma.message.create({
        data: {
          content,
          friendsId,
          userId,
        },
      });

I need to make sure that socket.emit has worked, to prevent a message from being created but not sent over the socket.
This is the main action performed with it:
if (receiverUser !== undefined) {
          io.to(receiverUser.socketId).emit("msg-recieve", {
            userId,
            friendsId,
            content,
          });
        } 


Use acknowledgements, also see examples.

You can add a callback as the last argument of the emit(), and this
callback will be called once the other side has acknowledged the event

So, send ack from client to server, and then you could move your code into callback, or call separate functions in case of error and success:
socket.timeout(5000).emit("send-msg", {
    content,
    friendsId,
    userId,
    receiverId,
}, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
        
        // the client did not acknowledge the event in the given delay

        handleError();

    } else {

        console.log(response);

        /*
        
        on client you'd need to return ack, for example:

        socket.on('send-msg', (arg1, callback) => {
            callback();
            ...

         */

        doStuff();
    }
});

